# import error in vscode meanwhile it is ok terminal

Tags: python, python-import, visual-studio-code

I have vscode on xubunutu and python 2.7 and 3.6.7. also I have made a virtualenv with python 3.6.7. In python 3 and the virtualenv I have installed matplotlib. But, when I import the matplotlib and run the code I receive import error. To be more sure, I have checked importing in the terminal and it was ok.
As I have not installed matplotlib in python2.7, it seems vscode still are not using python3 although at the bottom it shows python3.6.7.

In vscode after crtl+shift+p I selecet the interpreter and also change the path in setting.json to the corresponding address. for example for python 3:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

and for my virtualenv named "test":

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/home/joudy/test/bin/python"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the status bar (located in the bottom left corner) shows the correct interpreter/environment you are trying to use? 
[(image of the status bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhWwh.png)

If not, follow this [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on how to use python environments in VS Code.

Comment: yes. it shows the version of python correctly, but don't show when the virtual environment has been selected.